# Understanding problems of space

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

I've been trying to understand the concept of space for some time now, but I still can't grasp the essence of it. In high school math we've been using 2D- and 3D- Euclidean space. Now that I am visiting advance math courses I hear about Hilbert spaces and Banach spaces and so on...

Currently my understanding is that a Hilbert space has infinitely many dimensions and is complete. Correct?

I kept reading about spaces and I read things I don't understand:

1. There exist spaces without a distance measure. What are they good for?
2. Spaces can contain different numbers, e.g. some allow complex numbers, some don't. What is that good for? Don't I restrict my computations if I have a space that e.g. only contains rational numbers?
3. How is the inner product defined for a space with infinitely many dimensions?
4. Are there simple examples of a function space and a sequence space that I can understand?
5. How does the space influence my computations? Well I understand, that the knowledge about being in a certain space we can make some assumptions (at least that's what my teacher does) but can anyone give an example where a different space would lead to a different result?

Comment: I just give remarks. You could look it up. Check the following definitions: topological vector space, locally convex vector space, Banach space, Hilbert space in this order.

Answers involve concepts from various ranges of complexity. So just take it as sort of a hint what to look up.

1) A space has a metric if the topology is metrizable. There are spaces that pop up as spaces of maps on vector spaces with distance functions that do not allow any: e.g. the dual of a non-separable space with the weak* topology.

Comment: 2) A vector space is a certain algebraic structure over A scalar field. you can start with anyone you want. Sometimes you naturally have to use certain fields to examine what you are interested in.

Comment: 3) A Hilbert space (a potentially infinite dimensional, closed space with an inner product) comes with a definition of an inner product. You can not necessarily impose one on a given vector space. Look up $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ or $\ell^{2}(\mathbb{C})$. Note the difference in $\mathbb{C}$ vs. $\mathbb{R}$ and the fact that both spaces are well-defined after exchanging them. This is a hint towards my comment on (2).

Comment: 4) Maybe the vector space of real-valued functions on the set $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

5) There is a ton... $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete vector space, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not for example.

Comment: It's not that I did not look everything up, I'm switching between the topics back and forth and hope to understand it a little better. I just hoped that someone could give me an easier explanation (so why the negative votes?). thx for your comments, I will try to make sense of that information.

Comment: The questions perhaps are not posed so well, but they are good questions.

Comment: Maybe you can help me to phrase them better.

Comment: Why the negative votes? Maybe because your questions imply that some major areas of mathematics are of no use. Some mathematicians are proud to tell you that their work is useless, but others (the downvoters, maybe) think differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. There exist spaces without a distance measure. What are they good for?

Yes, there are things called topological spaces, which don't necessarily have a "distance" function. Even if you don't have a "distance" function, you can still describe the "separation" of points using things called "neighbourhoods". This is a pretty abstract idea, and it probably won't be much use to you unless you study more advanced areas of mathematics. You can get a lot done using "metric" spaces, which are ones that do have a distance function.

> 1. Spaces can contain different numbers ... Don't I restrict my computations

Yes, but sometimes you *want* to restrict things. Suppose you're doing something as simple as solving a quadratic equation. Depending on your application, sometimes you want complex roots, and sometimes you only want real ones.

> 1. How is the inner product defined for a space with infinitely many dimensions?

You're probably familiar with the $n$-dimensional space, in which each object is an $n$-tuple of real numbers $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$. There, the inner product is defined by $\left<x,y\right> = \sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i$. Now let $n$ become infinite, so that you have infinite sequences $(x_1,x_2, \ldots)$. Then you can define an inner product by $\left<x,y\right> = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_iy_i$. There are some details to worry about, but that's the basic idea.

Another example is spaces of functions. You can define an inner product of two functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ by an integral: $\left<x,y\right> = \int x(t)y(t)\,dt$.

> 1. Are there simple examples of a function space and a sequence space that I can understand?

See above.

> 1. How does the space influence my computations?

Let's use functions, again, as an example. Specifically, real-valued functions defined on the interval $[0,1]$. There are (at least) two obvious ways to measure the "distance" between two functions:
$$
\text{Using the area between their graphs:  } \quad \text{dist}(x,y) = \int_0^1|x(t)-y(t)|dt
$$
$$
\text{Using their maximum deviation:  } \quad \text{dist}(x,y) = \max\{|x(t)-y(t)| : 0 \le t \le 1\}
$$
These two ways of measuring distance give you two different "spaces". The objects in the space are the same in either case, but the way we measure distance is different. And these two different ways of measuring distance give different results. Imagine two functions that are very close to each other except in a tiny narrow region, where they differ by a value of 100. If you measure distance using the area method, it will be very small, but measuring with the maximum deviation method will give you an answer of 100.

I should emphasize that the discussion above is *very* sloppy and informal. I was just trying to convey some concepts, and there are many details that you need to worry about to make all this rigorous. But, you are a student of bioinformatics, not mathematics, so maybe intuitive understanding is more important to you than rigor. That's for you to decide.

Comment: Today, while reading a chapter about vector spaces and sub spaces I had an intuition and I think I understood something that I missed all the time: Is it correct that a space is something that contains "things" (e.g. vectors) and has "operations" (e.g. addition and inner product) and the result of every operation I can perform is again an element of this space? Bc if I have a sub vector space I can not find any operation to create a vector that is outside of that subspace.